# Change order np.argmax index is taken from

Tags: numpy

I have three matrixes as such:

```
one = np.empty((5,5))
one[:] = 10

two = np.empty((5,5))
two[:] = 10 

three = np.empty((5,5))
three[:] = 2
```

I then stack them:

```
stacked = np.dstack([one, two, three])
```

and finally determine the index with the maximum values:

```
t_max = np.argmax(stacked, axis=2)
```

I now want to determine the maximum value, but with a caveat.  If there are multiple depths with identical max values (as in my example) I want to return the index from the largest depth.

As it is now `t_max` returns:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
```

but I would like to return:

```
[[1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1]]
```

since the second depth has identical maximum values as the first, but has a larger depth as well.

EDIT:

I think I can just do `np.flip(stacked, axis=2)` first, but maybe this isn't the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For efficiency purposes, I would suggest using a `flipped` view and then getting the indices after subtracting from the last axis length, like so -

```
stacked.shape[-1] - stacked[...,::-1].argmax(-1) - 1
```

Another approach without flipping and a bit longer one, would be with comparison against the maximum value, using cumulative summation and then using `argmax` to catch the last ones of those matches, like so -

```
(stacked == stacked.max(-1,keepdims=1)).cumsum(-1).argmax(-1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [29]: stacked = np.random.randint(0,3,(2,5,3))

In [30]: stacked
Out[30]: 
array([[[2, 1, 2],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 0],
        [1, 2, 2]],

       [[2, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 2, 2],
        [1, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0]]])

In [31]: stacked.shape[-1] - stacked[...,::-1].argmax(-1) - 1
Out[31]: 
array([[2, 2, 2, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 2, 1, 0]])

In [32]: (stacked == stacked.max(-1,keepdims=1)).cumsum(-1).argmax(-1)
Out[32]: 
array([[2, 2, 2, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 2, 1, 0]])
```

Runtime test -

```
In [33]: stacked = np.random.randint(0,10,(1000,1000,100))

In [34]: %timeit stacked.shape[-1] - stacked[...,::-1].argmax(-1) - 1
1 loop, best of 3: 281 ms per loop

In [35]: %timeit (stacked == stacked.max(-1,keepdims=1)).cumsum(-1).argmax(-1)
1 loop, best of 3: 659 ms per loop
```